# Using bonferroni with t.tests & regression

Tags: p-value, bonferroni

I have theoretical knowledge of why we should use bonferroni; however, unfortunately not how.

I am conducting multiple t.tests, sometimes within the main data (number of t.tests = 5, number of main tests/regression = 2), and sometimes within the split data by gender (number of tests = 2).

I am wondering then whether I should conduct bonferroni separately for the main data and the split data.

using R, finding the adjusted p using bonferroni for the main data is then:

```
p.adjust(c(0.0012, 0.005, 0.0464, 0.003, 0.0321, 0.001, 0.002), method = "bonferroni")
```

and the same for the split data would then be:

```
p.adjust(c(0.0464, 0.0321), method = "bonferroni")
```

Am I doing this correctly? Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: And am I understanding it correctly that it is generally not preferred to do bonferroni on exploratory analyses? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bonferroni correction is an adjustment to the threshold of significance (i.e., alpha) for your p-value. This correction is made to account for inflated Type I error (the higher the chance for a false positive). It is a very straight forward statistic -- you simply divide your p-value by the number of independent hypothesis tests that you have conducted. If you are testing 9 hypotheses, and the standard alpha value in your field is .05, your Bonferroni corrected alpa is .05/9 = .006. This means any p-value you have that is above .006 (but below .05) is treated with suspicion.

Thus, your first step is to really specify how many hypotheses you are testing.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Yes that helps enormously, thanks!!